# sublime text 3 Switching tabs with keyboard

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3, key-bindings

you can't predict which tab you will get after hinting the keyboard with ctrl+tab   and you want to switch from tab to tab in sublime text 3? and you are looking for something "smart"? here how to do:

Comment: very out dated question... this question should be closed

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 3.1.1 has the following predefined shortcuts in the Key-Bindings (See under Preferences):

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+["], "command": "prev_view" },
{ "keys": ["super+shift+]"], "command": "next_view" },
{ "keys": ["super+alt+left"], "command": "prev_view" },
{ "keys": ["super+alt+right"], "command": "next_view" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+pagedown"], "command": "next_view" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+pageup"], "command": "prev_view" },
```

Seems more than enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

just add to the file …..Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap which you find in the menu clicking : Preferences > key bindings .
NB super mean the windows key in PC keyboard.

```
            { "keys": ["super+alt+right"], "command": "next_view_in_stack" },
            { "keys": ["super+alt++left"], "command": "prev_view_in_stack" },
            { "keys": ["ctrl+tab"], "command": "next_view" },
            { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+tab"], "command": "prev_view" }
```